# Using a debugOnly package in integration tests (MeteorJS)

Tags: meteor, continuous-integration, meteor-packages

I'm moving our test-data into a `debugOnly` package. This way I can ensure that no test-data will be available on production installations and the methods that clean the DB and create fixtures will be unavailable too. That means when we run our integration tests with the `--production` flag, the methods for creating fixtures will be unavailable.

Is it possible to tell `meteor` to include a specific package in a production run? Or are there other good ways of testing production builds with fixtures?